# Particle Info not working on Blender 2.8 with Eevee

Tags: node-editor, particles

The documentation for Blender 2.8 (https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/particle_info.html?highlight=particle%20info%20node)

[image]

I am trying to use the random property of a particle info node to affect the color and emission shader. It works when I render with cycles, but not when I render with Eevee.

Comment: Are you using cycles render?

Comment: @batFINGER Yes, but I could switch to Eevee if that makes any difference. Also, I just pulled the latest from the repository today 4/20/2019.

Comment: Ooops! I am sorry, I made a mistake here. The problem is that I don't see the effect of the particle info (on the material) in the viewport. I am going to update the question.

Comment: This link (https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/render/eevee/materials/nodes_support.html) does state that the particle info node is not supported in Eevee, so that answers part of the question. but how about the `Viewport Display`? If cycles is selected as the renderer, shouldn't the material behave as in the render? I am going to break this up into two different questions.

Comment: Good news to post here, this feature is prepared to keep going, official release a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tKpHuq9qEk&feature=youtu.be) and show the experimental version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This link (https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/render/eevee/materials/nodes_support.html) does state that the particle info node is not currently supported in Eevee, so that answers part of the question.

https://developer.blender.org/T59459

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but then I realized I was using the beta release from May 2018. So I just re-downloaded Blender 2.80 and it works fine now (ie Eevee supports the particle info node).

Comment: So far Blender 2.83 -> 2.90 does not, according to the documentation. 

I tested with 2.83.2 and it doesn't work for "index" (at least) in EEVEE while Cycles performs flawlessly.